# Show element where mouse is inside div (axis y)

Tags: javascript

I have a widget container where if I go to the right side, a dragger selector appears (mouseover).

I need to that dragger follow the mouse position in axis Y inside the widget container limits.

I have tried a lot of things but I'm not able to get the right position for the dragger.

```js
rh.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
  const draggerElement = event.target.parentNode.querySelector('.widget-dragger')

  if (draggerElement.style.opacity !== 1) {
    draggerElement.style.top = `${event.pageY - (event.target.offsetHeight / 2)}px`
    draggerElement.style.opacity = 1
  }
})
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rt0s8p7h/1/

Captures:

[image: example]

This is the rh element:

[image: example2]

It has 100% height of the widget container.

Dragger has absolute position inside the widget container.

Widget Container has relative position, so the dragger is limited inside the container.

Comment: Does this help: https://codepen.io/colinah/pen/MWeKMdz

Comment: I don't need to resize, I need the dragger to follow the mouse in axis Y when hovering the bar at the right

Answer (score 0):

Solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/rt0s8p7h/3/

```js
rh.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
  const draggerElement = event.target.parentNode.querySelector(".widget-dragger")

  if (draggerElement.style.opacity !== 1) {
    const rhRect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect()
    draggerElement.style.top = `${event.clientY - rhRect.top - draggerElement.offsetHeight/2}px`
    draggerElement.style.opacity = 1
  }
})
```

Also works for `mousemove` to follow the mouse cursor.